How do I verify the jms:properties sent in Mule 4 JMS publish with MUnit test?
I have the following JMS publish config and I would like to verify that prop1 and prop2 are sent with a given value when the connector is mocked.
<jms:publish
    doc:name="Place file on some queue"
    sendCorrelationId="ALWAYS"
    persistentDelivery="true"
    config-ref="JMS_ActiveMQ_REF"
    destination="some.queue.name">
    <jms:message
        correlationId="#[uuid()]">
        <jms:properties><![CDATA[#[{
            "prop1": vars.prop1,
            "prop2": vars.prop2
        }]]]>
        </jms:properties>
    </jms:message>
</jms:publish>

It is mocked using:
<munit-tools:mock-when doc:name="Mock Place file on some queue" processor=".*:.*">
<munit-tools:with-attributes>
    <munit-tools:with-attribute attributeName="doc:name" whereValue="#['Place file on some queue']" />
</munit-tools:with-attributes>
<munit-tools:then-return>
    <munit-tools:payload value="#[payload]" mediaType="application/xml" />
</munit-tools:then-return>

Previously with Mule 3 I would have checked the message.outboundProperties, but that is not an option with Mule 4.
Unfortunately I could not find a Mule 4 solution by searching, and the known AI-s could not help either.

The equivalent in Mule 4 is message.attributes but I don't know if you will see JMS properties there since those may be only part of the JMS message. Why do you expect them to be able to mock them?

The JMS publish processor is mocked because there is no ActiveMQ running during the MUnit test. My goal is unit testing the flow with the processor in it. I would like my test fail if e.g. one of the properties was not sent in the JMS message accidentally.

Mocking will only 'simulate' that a message processor is executed. Since these properties are part of the message being sent externally in the flow I don't think there is any use for them in the rest of the flow. You could try to see if there are attributes set after publishing a real JMS message. Otherwise is not something you could mock.

I think there is a bit of misunderstanding here. I don't want to mock the properties. I want to verify them. The sole purpose of the flow is sending that message with those properties. Yes, I can verify them in a complete environment with a real ActiveMQ, but my question is how to do that with MUnit. It is easy to do with Mule 3 by e.g. adding a spy on the the JMS publish processor then assert the value of message.outboundProperties.prop1. As outboundProperties are sent in the JMS message with Mule 3, no more check needed. I need a Mule 4 solution for the same if exists.

The mock seemed to try to mock the JMS publish operation. If not relevant to the question you should remove it from the test. Allow me to reiterate that I don't know if that is possible in Mule 4. I suggested to check the values of the attributes. Did you review if the message attributes show the JMS properties?

The mock in deed mocks the JMS publish operation. It is essential part of the question because I need a solution with the mocking in place. I'm not allowed to rely on the presence of a real queue in a MUnit test. Yes, I did review the message attributes. prop1turns into attributes.properties.userProperties.prop1 when the message goes through a real queue. attributes is null when the mock response created so I can not access or return it from the mock.

Try setting the attributes in the mock -in addition to the payload- to match what you observed in a real message.
Example:
<munit-tools:then-return>
    <munit-tools:payload value="#[payload]" mediaType="application/xml" />
    <munit-tools:attributes value="#[{
        properties:  {
            userProperties: {
                prop1: vars.prop1,
                prop2: vars.prop2
            }
        }
    }]" />
</munit-tools:then-return>


That would only help to verify the value of the flow variables prop1 and prop2. They can be checked in the validation part anyway. If there was a fault in the jms:properties e.g. wrong property was sent like "prop2": vars.prop1 the test would not detect it.

There is no way to test what the connector is actually sending over the wire, other than receiving the message and verifying there. The Mule 3 test would not detect it either. Mule 3 inbound/outbound properties are attributes in Mule 4.
